# Git: pre-receive hook to allow only merges and not direct commits into master

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks, git-commit

I have a problem creating a `pre-receive` hook on a git remote branch, doing what I want.

**What's the problem?**

Direct commits to the master branch should be not allowed. Only merges into the master branch should be allowed.

**Solution**

My solution until now is to check, if there are changes in the push from a user, where the master is affected. But the problem is that I can't differentiate if the change is a direct commit or a merge.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrefid newrefid refname
do
if [ "$refname" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        echo $(git merge-base $oldrefid $newrefid)
        echo "---- Direct commit to master branch is not allowed ----"
        echo "Changes only with a merge from another branch"
        exit 1
fi
done
```

Has anyone an idea, how to check if the change is a merge?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you get in a pre-receive hook is the previous and the new tip of the branch, so you're going to have to check the list of commits that got added, and see if any of them are not merges:

```
nonmerges=$(git rev-list --no-merges --first-parent $oldrefid..$newrefid | wc -l)
[ "$nonmerges" -eq 0 ] && exit 0
```

`--first-parent` limits the output to commits from the main line, i.e. commits that got merged in (reachable via second/third/... parent) are skipped.

Possibly complication: fast-forward merges (which are difficult to distinguish from a series of normal commits).

Comment: "fast-forward merges (which are difficult to distinguish from a series of normal commits)" AFAIK there is no way to distinguish a series of commits from a fast-forward merge. It's simply an update of the branch we merge into to the commit in question.

Comment: @Zeeker you can kind-of-guess at a fast-forward merge by checking whether the same commits exist on another branch. In some circumstances this may be sufficient evidence. It's far from error-proof, though.

Comment: I see but that would be quite far fetched. At least locally the reflog could make one smarter but that obviously excludes any remote we push to.

Comment: Well, we're make every merge with the parameter --no-ff so that should be no problem. It works wonderful very good!

Comment: "fast-forward-ness" is actually a property of a label move: a typical push of 1 or more merge commits is normally itself a fast-forward operation (and hence allowed without `--force`).

Comment: btw, is there a simple possibilty to check if the merge is ff and forbid it? That would be great, too!

Comment: @MarcelBalzer Not really. FF merges are indistinguishable from a normal series of commits. If you have certain restrictions on your workflow it may be feasible to detect a series of commits as FF-merged from another branch, but it's hairy and personally I prefer rejecting anything other than true merge commits for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @JanKrüger So does the above solution reject FF-merges? Because that is what I would like...

Comment: @Arne for the most part, yes. However, if you fast forward and bring in nothing but merge commits (along the first parent sequence), it looks like merges to this script (and will be accepted) even though technically the merges happened on another branch and were just "copied" by the FF.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the short answer: look at the value produced by:

```
git rev-list --count --max-parents=1 $oldrefid..$newrefid
```

You want this to be zero.  Read on for the explanation (and caveats).

---

Your loop has the right outline:

- read all ref updates;
- for those that update the branch(es) (or other references) you care about, perform some check.

The trick lies in performing the check.  Consider the two other pieces of information you receive, namely the old and new SHA-1 IDs, and that in these hooks, one (but not both) of these two SHA-1 IDs may be all `0`s (meaning the ref is being created or deleted).

To insist that the change not be a creation or deletion, your test should ensure that neither SHA-1 is all-zeros.  (If you're willing to assume that only deletion need to be checked you can just check that the new SHA-1 is not all-zero.  But if creation could occur—which is only the case if somehow the `master` branch gets deleted after all, e.g., by someone logging on to the server receiving pushes, and manually deleting it—you'll still need to make sure that the old SHA-1 is not all-zero for the final test.  Clearly this kind of deletion is *possible*, the question is whether you want to write code to handle the case.)

In any case, the most typical push simply updates the reference.  Note that any new commits have already been written to the repository (they'll be garbage-collected if you refuse the push), so your task at this point is to:

- find and verify any commits that the reference used to name, that it will no longer name (these are commits that would be removed by a non-fast-forward push); and
- find and verify any commits that the reference will name now, that it did not used to name (these are the new commits that would be added by a push, whether it is fast-forward or not: remember that a new push could remove one or more commits while adding one or more, at the same time).

To find these two sets of commits, you should use `git rev-list`, since that's precisely its job: to produce a list of SHA-1s specified by some expression.  The two expressions you want here are "all commit IDs find-able from one revision, that are not already find-able from some other ID".  In `git rev-list` terms these are `git rev-list $r1 ^$r2`,<sup>1</sup> or equivalently, `git rev-list $r2..$r1`, for two revision-specifiers `$r1` and `$r2`.  The two revspecs are, of course, just the old and new IDs for the proposed `push`.

The order of these two IDs determines which set of commits `git rev-list` lists: the ones that would be removed—this set is empty for a fast-forward operation—and the ones that would be added.

---

In this *particular* case, your goal is not to produce these lists of commits themselves (although that would work), but rather, to select something *from* these lists.

You may wish to prevent commit deletions (i.e., to enforce fast-forward-ness even if the user doing the `push` specified a force flag).  In this case, simply verifying that the "to be removed" list is empty suffices.  You can do that by making sure that the list is actually empty, or—simpler in a shell script—having `git rev-list` count them for you and check that the resulting number is zero.

You definitely wish to prevent additions that are *not* merges, but allow additions that are.  In this case, adding `--max-parents=1` (which can also be spelled `--no-merges`) tells `git rev-list` to suppress commits that have two or more parents, i.e., merges.  Adding `--count` gets you a count of commits that meet this "not a merge because zero or one parent" constraint.  If this count is zero, then any commits being added must by definition be merges.

Hence:

```
n=$(git rev-list --count --max-parents=1 $oldrefid..$newrefid)
if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "disallowed: push adds $n non-merge commit(s)" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

for instance, will suffice to enforce this particular constraint.

---

<sup>1</sup>Almost but not quite equivalent, you can write `git rev-list $r1 --not $r2`: the difference is that the effect of `--not` lingers, so that if you were to add yet another revision ID `$r3` the `--not` will apply to `r3`.  That is, `git rev-list A ^B C` means `yes-A, not-B, yes-C` but `A --not B C` means `yes-A, not-B, not-C`.  Note that in `rev-list` syntax, `B..A` means `A ^B`, i.e., exactly `B` is inverted.